# How to get two arrays by mapping a predicate over an input array with Ramda

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, ramda.js

Is there a concise way to achieve the same result as the below but:

- without mutation
- without iterating over the input array more than once
- using Ramda (preferably)

I thought about using reduce to update an accumulator object containing the passed/failed arrays, but I'm not sure if there was a smarter/less verbose option

```
const predicate = i => i % 2 === 0;
const predicatePassed = [];
const predicateFailed = [];

[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(i => predicate(i) ? predicatePassed.push(i) : predicateFailed.push(i))

// predicatePassed === [2, 4]
// predicateFailed === [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [R.partition](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#partition):

```js
const predicate = i => i % 2 === 0;

const [predicatePassed, predicateFailed] = R.partition(predicate)([1, 2, 3, 4]);

console.log(predicatePassed);
console.log(predicateFailed);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```